# Avoiding information leakage in CV folds with scaling

Tags: python, cross-validation, scikit-learn, data-leakage

Chapter 6 (Algorithm Chains and Pipelines) in the book *Introduction to ML with Python* made me aware of a common mistake when scaling data for cross validation: leaking information into the test set by scaling the training and test set together.

I wanted to make sure my implementation now is correct:

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)    
clf = SVC()

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(x_train_all, y_true):
    x_train, y_train = x_train_all[train_index], y_true[train_index]
    x_test, y_test = x_train_all[test_index], y_true[test_index]

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    x_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
    clf.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train)

    x_test_scaled = scaler.transform(x_test)
    y_prediction = clf.predict(x_test_scaled)
```

As comparison, beforehand I scaled the whole test set, which I believe is incorrect:

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)    
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train_all = scaler.fit_transform(x_train_all)
clf = SVC()

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(x_train_all, y_true):
    x_train, y_train = x_train_all[train_index], y_true[train_index]
    x_test, y_test = x_train_all[test_index], y_true[test_index]

    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_prediction = clf.predict(x_test)
```

Hopefully somebody can comment on whether my cross validation is now sound or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct in the sense that it does not suffer from data leakage.

However, it will not yield proper predicive abilities, so in that sense your computation is bad.

You can see that undesired behaviour when you try to predict a single test case: the scaling of the test data is not going to work then. In other situations, the problem is more subtle: your prediction will work only for representative data sets to be predicted together.

The solution is to consider the scaling parameters (center and scaling fractor) as *parts of the model*. That would make your prediction start by centering *with the center estimated on the training data* and scaling *with the scaling factors estimated on the training data*. Note that this is as stable as your training data is good, and doesn't have any problems with predicting single cases.

Comment: I am not 100% sure I understood your answer correctly.

I use this method as internal validation for my model and I'll never ever going to have just one single case for my prediction here. And as this data is selected by me, all data should be representative. But maybe I got it all wrong. Especially the last paragraph was not clear to me.